# Find a space in string and append character after

Tags: php, mysql, strpos, match-against

I am constructing a search query and would like to search the words seperatly if multiple are entered, currently i am doing:

```
   MATCH (P.`content`) AGAINST ('+$term' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But if the term had multiple words i would like `$term` to display like `'+multiple +word +term'`

So i need to check for a space in the string and append the + after the space.
I know i can use `strpos($string, " ")` to find the/A space but wont this stop after the first space it finds? would a preg_match be better?

Also am i right in thinking that `substr_replace($term, '+', $pos, 0);` will work to insert the character? but again will only be able to handle one space not multiple

Comment: Ive managed to get the correct reuslt but dont like the way ive done it...
    `$term = explode(' ',$term);`
    `$term = implode(' +',$term);`

does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: `str_replace("+", " ", $term);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was over thinking it `$term = str_replace(" ", " +", $term);` did what i need, thanks to  M A SIDDIQUI